# how to get a descendant from parent entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I can't seem to find a quick answer on how to get Datastore descendants given a reference to the parent entity.  Here's a quick example:

```
# a person who has pets
john=Person(**kwargs)

# pets
fluffy=Pet(parent=john, ...)
rover=Pet(parent=john, ...)

# lengthy details about john that are accessed infrequently
facts=Details(parent=john, ...)
```

1. How can I get the keys for fluffy, rover and facts using john or the key for john?
2. With john (or key) can I get key/entity for just facts (not rover, fluffy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [ancestor filter](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_ancestor):

```
kid_keys = db.Query(keys_only=True).ancestor(john).fetch(1000)
```

And you can get just facts by specifying the type of facts:

```
facts_key = db.Query(Details, keys_only=True).ancestor(john).get()
```

Using `get()` instead of `fetch()` assumes that john will have only one `Details` child. If that is not true, call `fetch` to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Adam's answer:  If you don't know the key name or key ID for `fluffy`, `rover` or `facts`, you can't construct the keys ahead of time based just on the entity or key for `john`.  You'll have to use ancestor queries, as in Adam's answer.

If, on the other hand, you *do* know the name or ID for those child entities (say, in a request handler where the ID comes in as part of the URL or something), you can construct their keys based on the `john` entity or its key.  E.g.:

```
# Build a key for the parent
john_key = db.Key.from_path('Person', 1)

# Build a key for the children
fluffy_key = db.Key.from_path('Pet', 1, parent=john_key)
rover_key = db.Key.from_path('Pet', 2, parent=john_key)

# Get all three at once
john, fluffy, rover = db.get([john_key, fluffy_key, rover_key])
```

These examples assume that all the entity keys have IDs, but if they have names you can just substitute the string names in place of the `int` IDs.